# MongoDB / Node.js: Swapping fields between different objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently writing a small Javascript application that allows you to reorder elements in a MongoDB database. Every entry in the database has a field called "order" representing it's position.

So, when you select an entry in the db to move "up", I want to swap the "order" field between the theoretically adjacent element with a position of "order - 1".

Here is the code I have so far:

```
collection.find({ "name": request.body.itemToMove }).toArray(function(err,doc) {
 ordernum = doc[0].order;
});
```

Here I'm grabbing the order field from the MongoDB element. I need to look up the database entry now with  ordernum - 1, the entry that is positionally above the entry we want to move up in the list.

Except apparently the object I get back using doc[0].order isn't a datatype I can work with using mathematical operators.

```
swapIndex = ordernum - 1
```

Does not work, however

```
console.log(ordernum);
```

Prints a number to the console. I also thought I might test out simply querying my database using the object itself, however the query fails.

```
collection.find({ "order": ordernum }).toArray(function(err,doc) {
//Do something
});
```

This fails as well. Is there any way for me to work out a way to swap the "order" fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to solve this far to specifically when you could use a more general approach.

say you are moving the item from position 5 to 3

```
db.items.update({"position": {"$gte": 3, "$lt": 5}}, {"$inc": 1})
// we now have 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6
db.items.update({"name": request.body.itemToMove}, {"$set": {"position": 3})
// and now it is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with the old 5 at 3
```

*Note: I didn't test those two lines, wrote them outta my head.*